# Install tensorflow in Conda environment on MacOS & later use YAML on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, yaml, conda

I prepared this Conda env.yml for a Conda environment on my Mac M1: My application is running fine in this environment. I am using Tensorflow version 2.7.0.

```
name: fresh_env
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - flask=2.1.3
  - nltk=3.7
  - numpy=1.22.3
  - pandas=1.4.3
  - pip=22.1.2
  - python=3.9.1
  - scikit-learn=1.0.2
  - tensorflow=2.7.0
```

However, when I try creating the same environment on Windows machine, Conda throws an error saying Tensorflow version 2.7.0 not found. When I try changing the version to 2.6.0 referring to this link https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow, it's working on Windows.

Now, how do I ensure I have a single env.yml working on both platforms?

Comment: How did you prepared this yml file? By-hand? or by `conda env create -f environment.yml`

Comment: Prepared by hand @AhmadAnis

Comment: Please prepare it by the above command and then try and let me know.

Comment: @AhmadAnis created yml file using `conda env export -f finalenv.yml` on Mac M1. Got this:
`
name: test_env
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - abseil-cpp=20210324.2=hbdafb3b_0
  - absl-py=0.15.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - .....................
prefix: /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test_env
`
When creating in Windows 10, got this error: `conda env create -f finalenv.yml`
`
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - python==3.9.1=hcbd9b3a_5_cpython
  - numpy==1.19.5=py39h54e5778_3
  - ......
  - flask==2.1.3=py39hca03da5_0
`

Comment: There is probably no way around doing a `conda search --subdir win-64 -c conda-forge tensorflow` to check which are the available versions

Answer (score 0):

**Test it empirically.** There is no expedient to know a particular YAML is going to be solvable on a given platform. Instead, test it.

One can simulate solving on other platforms with the `CONDA_SUBDIR` setting.  You may also want to include a `nodefaults` in the YAML to ensure that only the channels in the YAML are used.

**Test Solving**

```bash
## TIP: don't waste time with conda - use mamba
## Linux dry run (-d)
$ CONDA_SUBDIR=linux-64 mamba env create -n foo -d -f so-fresh-env.yaml

## macOS dry run (-d)
$ CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 mamba env create -n foo -d -f so-fresh-env.yaml

## Windows dry run (-d)
$ CONDA_SUBDIR=win-64 mamba env create -n foo -d -f so-fresh-env.yaml
```

I would automate this, either through a git pre-commit hook, or as part of CI (e.g., I [test environments with GitHub Workflows](https://github.com/mfansler/conda-envs-testing)).

---

For this particular case, we can't tightly lock down the versions because the TensorFlow builds have not been uniformly supported across platforms. The main issue is only `anaconda` channel builds for **win-64** and only `conda-forge` builds for **osx-64**. You did find that only v2.6.0 is common between them. However, `anaconda` channel uses `numpy>=1.20` for that build, and `conda-forge` channel uses `numpy>=1.19.2,<1.20`.

If you want a single YAML, I think you have to loosen the versions. For example, the following solves for all platforms:

**so-fresh-env.yaml**

```yaml
name: fresh_env
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - flask=2.1
  - nltk=3.7
  - numpy >=1.19,<1.22
  - pandas=1.4
  - pip
  - python=3.9
  - scikit-learn=1.0
  - tensorflow=2.6
```

Really, one could simply remove the `numpy` specification altogether, since `tensorflow` will tightly constrain it.